# XMLHttpRequest() Inside RequireJS Module

Tags: javascript, php, requirejs, lamp

all. I'm working on a browser-based RPG for fun as well as programming education. I recently learned RequireJS—which is amazing—but during the revision of my code to AMD, I ran into an application breaking snag.

In my original implementation, I used an `XMLHttpRequest()` request to get the player's selected hero from my server via a `GET` call to a `GetHero.php` file. `Asynchronous` calls are great, but I struggling with the timing of the callback function and continuation of the game—i.e. the game continues before the callback, which results in an error.

My questions are:
1) How can I get the game to wait for the XMLHttpRequest() to return a value before moving to the next block of code?
2) When in my RequireJS AMD should I execute this function?

I tried turning off asynchronous in the `.open()` function, but since RequireJS uses similar calls, I don't think it works as it would in the synchronous execution of my code. I've also omitted the majority of the code to isolate the specific issue and heighten readability.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me understand this!

> main.js

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "assets/js",
  deps: ["game"],
  paths: {
    jquery: "lib/jquery-3.3.1.min",
    bootstrap: "lib/bootstrap.min",
    game: "game",
    hero: "models/hero",
    getHero: "models/getHero",
    stats: "models/stats",
    heroClasses: "models/heroClasses"
  },
  shim: {
    bootstrap: ["jquery"]
  }
});
```

> game.js

```
define(["hero", "bootstrap"], function (h) {
  Hero = h;
  console.log(Hero);
  console.log(Hero.Stats.Get("str"));
  console.log(Hero.Stats.GetInfo()); // <==== this fails
});
```

> hero.js

```
define(["stats"], function (s) {
  Stats = s;
  return {
    Stats: Stats
  };
});
```

> stats.js

```
define(["getHero"], function(myHero) {

  var Info = myHero; // returns hero obj "{ name: "Hero", level: 1, etc..}"

  var _HeroClasses = heroClasses;

  var _GetInfo = function (arr) {
    return Info;
  };

  return {
    GetInfo: _GetInfo
  };
});
```

> getHero.js

```
define([], function () {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            return myObj;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/game/assets/php/GetHero.php", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

> GetHero.php

```
<?php
// TODO create MYSQL call to load hero
echo '{ "id": 0, "name": "Ryan", "classId": 0, "level": 50, "exp": 251 }';

?>
```

> Updated Code: (Working, but likely an ugly/poor solution)
>
> -- game.js (Updated)

```
var a = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Loading...";
    Hero = h;
    resolve(true);
  });
  a.then(function() {
    Hero.Stats.GetInfo();
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Ready";
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error('There was an error 2!', err.statusText);
  });
```

> -- getHero.js (Updated)

```
define([], function () {
  return function (method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
          reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText
          });
        }
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      };
      xhr.send();
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: I think you need to use promises.

Comment: I was thinking that, but have never used them before. From what I gather a promise is made with a `.then()` as the call and `.catch()` if there is an error. Think I should put it in the `status.js` file? Are you familiar with promises?

Comment: Yes, a little familiar. I used them extensively in a 6-month project last year. & You've got the right idea. Hopefully this helps: https://hackernoon.com/search?q=http%20requests%20in%20react

Comment: Thank you admcfajn, I will review that doc. I got the code to work, however I'm unsure if I executed the promises in the most effective way. I posted the updates above and would appreciate feedback.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the later reply. It looks alright to me. You don't need to use `document.getElementById("message")";` every time. You can do var `messageElem = document.getElementById("message") /* other code */ messageElem.innerHTML = "Ready"` I find this keeps the code cleaner